# VS2019 XML documentation file will not uncheck

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I turned on XML Documentation in an VS2019 ASP.Net Core 3.1 project (Properties > Build > XML documentation file).  I want to uncheck the option, but it won't stay unchecked!  I have unchecked the box a ton of different ways, including selecting "All Configurations" each time I close and open properties, it is always back on.  Then I went searching the project files for where it is referenced and it isn't!

Where is this stored?
how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I was able to solve it by deleting

```
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

from the .csproj file, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc).

I wasn't able to understand why Visual Studio wasn't updating that configuration, though.